# Android image not showing in custom dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

I've made a custom dialog in androidstudio (Java) but from a certain activity (google maps) the images are not showing, while when calling from another activity (basic activity), the images are showing. i haven't gotten a clue what the difference is between the two.

[image]

But when run and called from the app, it looks like this.

[image]

While the same dialog started from another activity is showing ok.

[image]

What could be the issue here?

This is the XML for that layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="1000dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:cardCornerRadius="20dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dlg_sa_background"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/dlg_bckgrnd_action" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dlg_sa_tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Starting new Action"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="48sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dlg_sa_btnOk"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_dialog"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dlg_sa_btnCancel"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_dialog"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dlg_sa_tvContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="Dialog Content"
            android:textSize="34sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/dlg_sa_btnCancel"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dlg_sa_tvTitle" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/dlg_sa_background"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dlg_sa_tvTitle"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/purpleline" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Could you share the code of the XML layout?

Comment: @Wang i've edited the post with the XML layout

Comment: Are you making the view with id `dlg_sa_background` gone in the maps activity ?
Because the image with id `imageView5` is constrained to the start of the first one, so it might not be visible if the `dlg_sa_background` is gone.
Maybe the start constraint of `imageView5` should be to the parent instead.

Comment: i tried pointing it to parent, i tried several things. but it never shows. also the background is not showing at all. you can see it in the images